# passwd command outputs 'password unchanged` when the password was changed

Tags: command-line, server, password, pam, passwd

I'm running on Ubuntu 20.04 server and trying to change the password of the current user using `passwd` command.
This is the output I get:

```
Changing password for ubuntu.
Current password:
New password:
Retype new password:
Password has been already used. Choose another.
passwd: Have exhausted maximum number of retries for service
passwd: password unchanged
```

However the password was changed. I'm logging now with the new password.
Why is this happening?
How to get the output of the command to reflect what happened?

After seeing the output I tried to login with the old password and was denied. The new one was the correct one.

This is the `/etc/pam.d/common-password` file:

```
# /etc/pam.d/common-password - password-related modules common to all services
#
# This file is included from other service-specific PAM config files,
# and should contain a list of modules that define the services to be
# used to change user passwords.  The default is pam_unix.

# Explanation of pam_unix options:
#
# The "sha512" option enables salted SHA512 passwords.  Without this option,
# the default is Unix crypt.  Prior releases used the option "md5".
#
# The "obscure" option replaces the old `OBSCURE_CHECKS_ENAB' option in
# login.defs.
#
# See the pam_unix manpage for other options.

# As of pam 1.0.1-6, this file is managed by pam-auth-update by default.
# To take advantage of this, it is recommended that you configure any
# local modules either before or after the default block, and use
# pam-auth-update to manage selection of other modules.  See
# pam-auth-update(8) for details.

# here are the per-package modules (the "Primary" block)
password    requisite      pam_pwquality.so retry=3
password    [success=1 default=ignore]  pam_unix.so obscure use_authtok try_first_pass sha512
# here's the fallback if no module succeeds
password    requisite      pam_deny.so
# prime the stack with a positive return value if there isn't one already;
# this avoids us returning an error just because nothing sets a success code
# since the modules above will each just jump around
password    required       pam_permit.so
# and here are more per-package modules (the "Additional" block)
# end of pam-auth-update config
password required pam_pwhistory.so remember=5
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question to add the output of `cat /etc/pam.d/common-password`

Comment: added the content of the `/etc/pam.d/common-password` file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`pam_pwhistory.so`](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/lunar/man8/pam_pwhistory.8.html) is a PAM module and so is [`pam_pwquality.so`](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/lunar/man8/pam_pwquality.8.html), [`pam_unix.so`](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/lunar/man8/pam_unix.8.html) and others.

When stacked in the file `/etc/pam.d/common-password`, they are invoked in the same order they are stacked in ... So, breaking down what is happening in your case(*i.e. in the order you stacked those modules*):

First, your password is evaluated for quality by:

```
password    requisite      pam_pwquality.so retry=3
```

If it passes that, then it is changed with:

```
password    [success=1 default=ignore]  pam_unix.so obscure use_authtok try_first_pass sha512
```

So, as you see, at this point your new password is accepted and set (*`pam_unix.so` is the module that changes your password*) without checking your user password history whatsoever.

Later, what this module:

```
password required pam_pwhistory.so remember=5
```

does and result in, is merely printing:

```
Password has been already used. Choose another.
```

and `passwd` exits with failure as per the status of the last invoked module:

```
passwd: Have exhausted maximum number of retries for service
passwd: password unchanged
```

when it's too late.

To fix that, stack PAM modules in the correct order that yields the result you expect i.e. like this:

```
# /etc/pam.d/common-password - password-related modules common to all services
#
# This file is included from other service-specific PAM config files,
# and should contain a list of modules that define the services to be
# used to change user passwords.  The default is pam_unix.

# Explanation of pam_unix options:
#
# The "sha512" option enables salted SHA512 passwords.  Without this option,
# the default is Unix crypt.  Prior releases used the option "md5".
#
# The "obscure" option replaces the old `OBSCURE_CHECKS_ENAB' option in
# login.defs.
#
# See the pam_unix manpage for other options.

# As of pam 1.0.1-6, this file is managed by pam-auth-update by default.
# To take advantage of this, it is recommended that you configure any
# local modules either before or after the default block, and use
# pam-auth-update to manage selection of other modules.  See
# pam-auth-update(8) for details.

# here are the per-package modules (the "Primary" block)
password    requisite      pam_pwquality.so retry=3
password    required     pam_pwhistory.so remember=5 use_authtok
password    [success=1 default=ignore]  pam_unix.so obscure use_authtok try_first_pass sha512
# here's the fallback if no module succeeds
password    requisite      pam_deny.so
# prime the stack with a positive return value if there isn't one already;
# this avoids us returning an error just because nothing sets a success code
# since the modules above will each just jump around
password    required       pam_permit.so
# and here are more per-package modules (the "Additional" block)
# end of pam-auth-update config
```

Notice, as well, the addition of the `use_authtok` option to prevent the module from prompting for a password and use the previous stacked module's password instead ... Use that option if you have to use another module like `pam_pwquality.so` before it or otherwise that option should not be used.

Comment: wow! thank you very much! figured what each module does, however didn't think the order was causing the issue.